# What is the Best way to get only 10 rows in django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I have Grid-view it only show 10 records on time .
What is the best way to get from database only 10 rows?
Is `MyModel.objects.all()[10:20] approprate` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. The [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) also have examples on this.

```py
>>> Entry.objects.all()[5:15]
```

Since I don't know your use case, maybe [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/) is also something that might suite your needs.